# Why is assigning events to variables of type delegate possible in C#?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

One way to create an event in C# is as follows:

`public event DelegateName EventName`

In the above example `Delegate` name is of type `delegate` and `EventName` is of type `event`. The event needs to know about the signature of the delegates which can be attached to it, but it is not the same type.

In this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-create-a-binding-in-code?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#example) in the Microsoft docs I came across the following:

`public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`

Later on, the following is done:

`PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;`

This is extremely confusing to me. How can a variable of type `PropertyChangedEventHandler` be assigned an event?

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: actually `event` is not a type. So strictly speaking `EventName ` is not of type `event`. Events are just multi-cast delegates, so you can add and assign handlers to them. Think of them like properties and fields. The delegate is the backing field, the event is the property that wraps that backing-field by adding a getter and a setter.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain yes, that is correct. It says here that events can be *members* of types, but the implication is that they are not types themselves. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I'm a bit skeptical of your claim that events are "just multicast delegates". Does it state that anywhere in the official documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can a variable of type PropertyChangedEventHandler be assigned an event?

Because this is a *field-like event*. You can only assign to it or read from it *within the declaring class itself*. Everywhere else, that name refers to the event rather than the field.

From the [C# standard section 14.8.2](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/classes.md#1482-field-like-events):

> Within the program text of the class or struct that contains the declaration of an event, certain events can be used like fields. To be used in this way, an event shall not be abstract or extern, and shall not explicitly include event_accessor_declarations. Such an event can be used in any context that permits a field.

Comment: I don't fully understand it but I will take it to be correct for now

Comment: I don't understand either. What does it mean for an event to be "used like a field"?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride: Read like a field, as per in the question, or assigned like a field e.g. `PropertyChanged = null;`. Both are included as examples within the linked section of the standard.